# How to get a sortable portlets position and update it when moved?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, portlet, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently working with jQuery UI sortable portlets and PHP, and I need to be able to get the number position where each portlet is and update it when moved.

The portlet in the 1st position should always say `Position 1`, and the portlet in the 2nd Position should always say `Position 2`.

The trick is that I want it to update every time that I move a portlet, so that the portlet in the 1st Position is ALWAYS `Position 1` and so on. This is because I am moving unique data in these portlets, and the Position value will determine what priority this information is displayed on another page.

So how do I get and display a portlets position on each portlet, and update it whenever it is moved?

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: ".portlet-header",
    cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
    placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"    
});
$( ".portlet" )
    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
    .find( ".portlet-header" )
    .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
});
</script>

<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
?> 
<div class="portlet" id='portlet<?php echo $i; ?>'>

    <div class="portlet-header">
        <div>Position:<span id="value<?php echo $i; ?>"></span></div>
        <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
                  var portletPosition = $('#portlet<?php echo $i; ?>').sortable("serialize");
                  $("#value<?php echo $i; ?>").html(portletPosition);
             });
        </script>
    </div>

//Unique Portlet data

</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this is not exactly what you want, but in the code it saves the portlet order to a cookie, and retreives again when the page is opened. you can modify it to suit your needs http://technico.qnownow.com/developing-a-portal-with-drag-and-drop-portlets-using-jquery/